# Bootstrap row not taking up full height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass

Anything I tried did not work out.
Whether it was a simple

```
height: 100%
```

or trying out

```
flex-grow: 1
```

Nothing really worked.
I'm talking about [this site I'm currently working on](https://sann-fly.digital-h.de/checkout/?from=DUS&to=PRN&fromDate=01.08.2020&adults=1&children=0&babies=0):
[image]

Notice that the dashed vertical line does not reach the top and bottom of the container - as the element which the style is attached to (the row) doesn't want to take up full height.

Help, please?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

remove below code this will work.

```
.align-items-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

You can remove align-items-center class from

```
<div class="row align-items-center no-gutters">
```

After that if you want padding then you can apply it to inner div.
On this class.

```
.bo__flight-row {
  padding: 12px 0px;
}
```

Hope this will solve you problem.

See below the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Isn't ```align-items-center``` the recommended way to align children within a parent flex? Hardcoding values is not a good practice.

Comment: I am agree with you but if you see the website then you will get to know that in that website already lots of hardcoded values are available it means it doesn't matter to the developer of this website so we can hardcode.

Answer (score 0):

Your row takes the height of the child with maximum height which is the middle column containing the `div` with `class="bo__price_section"`. Reduce its height and see if it works for you.

As a suggestion, remove padding for `.bo__price_wrapper`.

[image]